# Generate Lomax Random Numbers in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, simulation

How can I Generate Lomax Random(Paretto Type II) Numbers using R?

If,U∈[0,1) is uniformly distributed random variable, then

L(xm,α)=P(xm,α)−xm

generates Lomax distributed random variable.

Comment: `VGAM` has a function `rlomax` to generate random numbers from a Lomax distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `VGAM::rlomax` it's not difficult to write your won [Lomax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution) random number generator using [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

The cdf of the Lomax distribution with a `shape` and `scale` parameter is given by `F(x) = 1 - (1 + x / scale)^(-alpha)`. All we need to do is solve `F(F^(-1)(x)) = x` for `F^(-1)(x)`, where `x ~ Unif(0, 1)`.

With that solution we can define the following function to draw Lomax random samples

```
rlomax.its <- function(N, scale, shape) {
    scale * ((1 - runif(N)) ^ (-1/shape) - 1)
}
```

We now draw `N = 1e5` samples from a Lomax distribution with `scale = 1` and `shape = 2` and compare with samples drawn from `VGAM::rlomax`

```
library(VGAM);
N <- 1e5;
set.seed(2017);
x.VGAM <- rlomax(N, scale = 1, shape3.q = 2)
x.ITS <- rlomax.its(N, scale = 1, shape = 2)

summary(x.VGAM);
#Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.
#0.0000   0.1536   0.4143   0.9985   1.0006 925.0784

summary(x.ITS);
#Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.
#0.0000   0.1548   0.4158   1.0016   1.0086 280.3248
```

Let's compare the density plots for different sample sizes using both methods.

```
set.seed(2017);
bind_rows(map(
    setNames(2:5, paste0("N=10^", 2:5)),
    ~list(ITS = rlomax.its(10^(.x), 1, 2), VGAM = rlomax(10^(.x), 1, 2))),
    .id = "N") %>%
    gather(key, value, -N) %>%
    ggplot(aes(log10(value), fill = key)) +
    geom_density(alpha = 0.4) +
    facet_wrap(~ N)
```

[image]

Obviously as `N` gets larger the distributions from both methods converge.

---

As to which method is faster, we can run a quick `microbenchmark` based on drawing `N=1e6` Lomax samples from both methods

```
library(microbenchmark);
res <- microbenchmark(
    ITS = rlomax.its(1e6, 1, 2),
    VGAM = rlomax(1e6, 1, 2))
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#  ITS  79.22709  84.11703  88.48358  86.29181  91.07074 109.3536   100  a
# VGAM 159.56578 175.88731 218.92212 183.09769 222.64697 359.9311   100   b

library(tidyverse)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Let's take a look at the dependence of runtime as a function of drawn samples

```
library(tidyverse);
library(ggthemes);
res <- map_df(seq(2, 6, length.out = 20), function(x)
    cbind(x = 10^(x), microbenchmark(
        ITS = rlomax.its(10^(x), 1, 2),
        VGAM = rlomax(10^(x), 1, 2))))
res %>%
    mutate(N = factor(as.numeric(factor(x)))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = N, y = log10(time), colour = expr)) +
    geom_tufteboxplot(outlier.colour="transparent") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_x_discrete(
        breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20),
        labels = paste0("10^", 2:6))
```

[image]

I don't have time to explore this further, but it turns out that on average the inverse sampling method is slightly (but consistently) faster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It helps me. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome @MaheshD; please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you will help future SO members.